# What is the difference between two ways of calling copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
class SmartPointer
{
int* _data;
public:
    explicit SmartPointer(int* data) : _data(data)
    {}
};
```

This code compiles:

```
SmartPointer p(nullptr);
```

But this one doesn't:

```
SmartPointer p = nullptr; // error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'SmartPointer'
```

Aren't these two ways of calling the copy constructor equivalent?

Comment: They are not equivalent.  The first one is direct-initialization, the second one is copy-initialization.  Neither involves the copy constructor.

Comment: Assigment operator is not the same as copy constructor.

Comment: @Ripi2 There's no assignment operator in the code.

Comment: i tried to fix "two ways of copy constructor" (there is only one) while trying to keep the answer valid, if you dont like it just reroll the edit

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with calling copy constructor; I think you meant two ways of *initialization*.

The 1st one is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which considers all the appropriate constructors, including `explicit` constructors. The 2nd one is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which only considers non-`explicit` ones.

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.